# Evaluate Your Site -- A Check for Quality

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

One of the most important aspects of being a Stack Exchange site is quality. Yes, there are lots of metrics that one can use to "measure" a site, but we don't really care about those as much as we care about a site providing expert answers to good questions. To that end, we're introducing a self-evaluation to our sites!

This process is currently still in the midst of being put together, but you all are going to be a lucky early-adopter! Here's a rough guide:

- Below, you'll find ten questions randomly selected from your site.
- For each question, search the internet for the question as if you were the asker!
- If our answer is good (complete, well-written, answers the question, found in search results, etc) then **vote it up**!
- If our answer is bad (incomplete, poorly-written, off-topic, unfindable, etc) then **vote it down**!

Comment with anything you feel is worth noting, or to explain your voting choice. We have a rough guide to better/par/worse [right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQxi7.png). If your result is par, make a choice to vote up or down based on your instincts!

Ultimately, remember that our goal is to make the internet a better place. If you find yourself torn between the options, or if you can't decide, ask yourself: does this question and/or answer make the internet better? That should help you decide.

**This eval will close on March 21st! Get your answers in by then!**

Comment: Example of another site that did this: [Judaism self-evaluation](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/836/site-self-evaluation-how-are-you-doing).

Comment: Examples of `better`: [one](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4231/how-does-copyright-apply-to-illustrations-and-cover-art) and [two](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4249/do-any-epublishing-systems-honor-fixed-poetry-formatting).

Comment: Examples of `worse`: [one](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4257/why-shouldnt-i-use-a-pen-name) and [two](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4233/how-can-i-work-more-efficiently-when-writing-multiple-pieces-of-fiction-at-the-s).

Comment: Related (and recent): http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/446/examples-of-clear-and-answerable-questions-on-writers

Comment: Thank you for your help, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

[How to write realistic female dialogue](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4660/how-to-write-realistic-female-dialogue)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score 2):

[Scientific Citation](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4627/scientific-citation)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Googling "citation format" readily turns up APA, MLA, Chicago, and Wikipedia, and a quick scan of those says there's not a single universal style (the question).  However, tha answers to this question consolidate some of that information in one place.  How should I vote?

Comment: @MonicaCellio - that's an upvote to me.

Answer (score 1):

[APA (sixth edition) citation for the Fourth Assessment Report](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4615/apa-sixth-edition-citation-for-the-fourth-assessment-report)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score 1):

[Return to section context after a subsection](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4636/return-to-section-context-after-a-subsection)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Hard to search for this question. I tried "formatting end subsection" and similar; got a lot of TeX answers but nothing on how the layout should visually look.

Answer (score 0):

[How to further improve the flow and crispness in the essay?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4616/how-to-further-improve-the-flow-and-crispness-in-the-essay)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: As Standback indicated elsewhere, this is a critique question, and it's not really relevant to this. Nobody will be googling this question.

Answer (score 0):

[Any good side-by-side editor for script translation?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4652/any-good-side-by-side-editor-for-script-translation)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Recommendation question, though its answer's pretty applicable.

Answer (score 0):

[citation for source from which a list of references was drawn?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4677/citation-for-source-from-which-a-list-of-references-was-drawn)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Answer (score 0):

https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4667/american-english-is-it-acceptable-sentence-structure-to-write-may-god-have-co

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: This question was closed as off-topic; I'm not sure it should be relevant to this survey.

Answer (score -1):

[Do these starting paragraphs make you want to keep reading?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4663/do-these-starting-paragraphs-make-you-want-to-keep-reading)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: This is a critique question; highly localized by nature. Probably won't be searched for, and not addressed anywhere else. I think this question is n/a for our purposes.

Comment: @Standback - we could compare critique questions to other critique sites (critters, etc.), but that would probably reflect badly on us since they exist to do critiques.

Comment: @justkt - agreed.  Even if critique is on-topic here, this isn't a critique site and we'll never be as good as sites dedicated to that purpose.  Nor should we strive to be.

Answer (score -1):

[Picture-based Identification Dictionary](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4617/picture-based-identification-dictionary)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Googling "visual dictionary" gets some _cool_ results.